# Twitter Bootstrap - how to make modal window responsible on mobile devices?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have an issue with Twitter bootstrap modal window on mobile devices - when I load the modal window there, the screen get dark, but the contact form in the modal window is nowhere.

I browsed SO and found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437151/twitter-bootstrap-modal-on-mobile-devices) - the answer with 16 upvotes could be working.

My concern is - where can I found these files? My app is running on RoR framework and I don't see these Twitter Bootstrap files - in the main CSS file I have only:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

How can I update those files?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you used the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem.

On my system ( OS X using RVM) I believe this is where it's kept:

~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.9/vendor/toolkit/twitter/bootstrap/responsive.less