# Twitter bootstrap: modal on mobile phones

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to figure out why I can't seem to click on anything inside the modal when it comes up (on a mobile device that is - it works OK in a pc browser). 
I have a code like this which is a basic modal from twitter bootstrap:

```
<!-- Modal -->

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3 id="myModalLabel">choose!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="row-fluid">
       <form>
         <fieldset>
             <select class="input-large">
             <option value="0">10:15</option>
             <option value="1">12:45</option>
             <option value="2">13:15</option>
            </select>
         </fieldset>
       </form>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
   </div>
</div> <!-- modal END -->
```

And this modal is opened by javascript event. It opens well enough, but on my phone I can't click (or i miss all the time?) the buttons or hit the select field.
Any thoughts on that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/adamdehaven/ECUUR/

Comment: Did you try accessing it on mobile device? It doesn't work for me ..

Comment: It works perfect on my iPhone 5 running the latest version of iOS. Visit this on your phone: http://jsfiddle.net/adamdehaven/ECUUR/show/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution..if anyone will have the same issue.
Just added 'active' class to the modal and it's working ok now.

```
class="modal hide fade active"
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It is caused by the inclusion of `bootstrap-responsive.css` (v2.0.3 in my case) and it affects both the proper display of the modal and its edition when you tap the input field and the keyword pops-up.
I slightly modified the patch presented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437151/twitter-bootstrap-modal-on-mobile-devices) StackOverflow question with this:

```
.modal { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 20px !important; 
    right: 3%; 
    left: 3%;
    width: auto; 
    margin: 0; 
}
```

in both `@media (max-width: 480px)` and `@media (max-width: 767px)` media queries and it seems to work fine.

Comment: More than 3 years later, I needed to add a modal to an old bootstrap 2 site and this helped. Thank you!

Note that there is no point in including it in both media queries; ```@media (max-width: 767px)``` will apply to all smaller screen sizes and is sufficient on its own.