# Bootstrap Unwanted space on the bottom of modal-footer after using the unofficial Bootstrap Modal modification

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I used [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437151/twitter-bootstrap-modal-on-mobile-devices) for Bootstrap modals on mobile devices as a base for some new code:

**bootstrap-responsive.css**

```
.modal { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 3%; 
    right: 3%; 
    left: 3%;
    bottom:3%; 
    width: auto; 
    margin: 0; 
}
.modal-body { 
    height: 60%; 
}
```

**bootstrap.css**

```
.modal-body { 
    max-height: 350px; 
    padding: 15px; 
    overflow-y: auto; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
 }
```

The problem is I'm having is I get extra space at the bottom of the modal.

[image: Preview]

How can I remove this space?

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Snippet/NewNv/16/) that demonstrates the issue.

Try changing the height of the browser in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m/xne/#) with a width of 480. The modal-footer should stick at the bottom but its not, when I remove the `bottom:3%` in `.modal` everything looks fine like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Snippet/NewNv/19/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/m/nve/#) but the height of `.modal` overlaps the height of the screen and its not responsive

Comment: Could you post your HTML/make a JSFiddle? Try bottom: 0; in your own stylesheet

Comment: Remove the padding property in .modal-body css

Comment: just created the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check to see if the orientation is landscape - and minimize the size of the modal-body accordingly

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/NewNv/21/)**

```
@media only screen 
and (orientation : landscape) { 
  .modal-body { 
        height: 160px;  
    }
}
```

---

Oh and by the way:

In the fiddle I fixed up the rounded corners of the model as well by adding the class:

```
.modal-footer
{
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
```

Comment: Already done that..but if i view the site on mobile landscape mode i can't see the footer.

Comment: just tested on devices.. works perfect..but what should i add so that the height of modal-body is not 160px on tablet devices. also had problem on small devices. the footer button cannot be seen.

Comment: devices with small heights.

Comment: You can target large/small devices with media queries in addition to orientation here's a link with many examples of media queries per device: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ also take a look at this snippet: http://snipplr.com/view/67341/

Comment: The above links should suffice to take care of tablets/small devices... if not, let me know and I'll update my answer with examples

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is your form inside the Modal.
Put this to your CSS.

```
.modal form{ margin: 0 !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding-bottom:

```
.modal-body { 
    max-height: 350px; 
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: auto; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code if u try commenting the bottom attribute given to the modal, i think this is what u r looking for.

```
.modal { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 3%; 
    right: 3%; 
    left: 3%;
    /*bottom:3%;*/  /* if u comment this the issue gets resolved */ 
    width: auto; 
    margin: 0; 
}
```

Also make change your modal footer css so it takes the same rounded-corners as the modal

```
.modal-footer
{
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
```