# Twitter Bootstrap - unwanted space above the footer in Mobile App

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, layout

My question is similar to the question here:

[Bootstrap Unwanted space on the bottom of modal-footer after using the unofficial Bootstrap Modal modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609977/bootstrap-unwanted-space-on-the-bottom-of-modal-footer-after-using-the-unofficia)

But, i am not using Modal and the issue only really bothers me in Landscape mode.

This is a photo (apologies) of what I mean.

I am totally stumped. Apart from the link I gave above I cannot find any thing else relating to this?

[image]

Just to confirm - want get rid of the white space.

And this is my current markup:

```
<div style="background-color: black;">
    <nav id="TopMenuBar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="background-color: black;">           
       my top content
    </nav>

    <div class="row mainBody" id="Contents" style="margin: 0; background-color: black;">
       my body content
    </div>

    <div id="BottomMenuBar" class="container-fluid">
       my footer content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make it a more complete code example (preferably a code snippet or jsFiddle) if you want this to be answered

Comment: Hi,I am not sure how you i want me to add to this? I could include the HTML tag, head and title. I could also include the link to the Twitter bootstrap file?  The behavior would be the same without any additional html elements ie the buttons I am showing... the Link I gave also shows another example of this?

Comment: All, and only all, code needed to reproduce the problem. If I drop this into codepen it looks like http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/yyajjj. That doesn't look like your picture, nor like a complete example. Are you using Bootstrap 2 or 3?

Comment: Hi ? Thanks for taking the time to respond. Like I said the behaviour is the same with or without the buttons do having the buttons makes no difference to the behaviour which is further demonstrated in that link I included. I am confused but not upset :) as to why you need my buttons included? I believe in focusing on the behaviour? The buttons do not change that

Comment: Sorry keep hitting post button - on mobile on middle of field at mo - was going to add using twitter 3. Thanks :)

Comment: The link is about Bootstrap 2 and modal windows, I'm not sure if it applies to this case. As unfortunately I can't reproduce it in my codepen I'm afraid I can't help you :(

Comment: Hi, that's ok.  Appreciate ur time. I should have added to my question this is behavior is in mobile and nor desktop. Thanks for pointing our the Boostrap 2 thing :)