# How to show the Bootstrap modal dialog at center of the screen on all browsers and all devices?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, popup, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Bootstrap modal dialog to show some information into a pop-up but I'm not able to show this pop-up at the center of the screen. I want to show this pop-up at the center of screen on all browsers and all devices. For this I tried the following CSS code but it didn't work out for me:

```
.modal { 
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent; }

.modal-body { 
  display: inline-block; 
  background-color: #FFF; }



.modal img { min-width: none!important; }
```

The **[link](http://smartrebate.eywaharvest.com/)** if you want to test.

There upon clicking on the green colored Details button you will be able to see the modal pop-up. I want this pop-up at the center of the screen.

Can someone please help me in this regard?

Comment: It's not about the bootstrap. It's somewhere in your codes.

Comment: @Wilf:In all browsers and on all devices like smartphones, ipad, any tablet, etc.

Comment: Hang on I'm checking your codes... tick tock

Comment: see the answer i have given just now

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommended give `Bootstrap Modal` extension a try:

> Extends the default Bootstrap Modal class. Responsive, stackable, ajax and more. — [GitHub](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal)

Centered, responsive modal dialog was one of the important requirements for one of my projects a couple of years ago. So I started using extension and totally forgot the default plugin and its problems (such as background scrolling).

It's really easy to [install](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal#installation-). See the live demo [here](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/).

Comment: @jibiel:I tried the extension you suggested. But still having some issues. 1) The pop-up is not coming on iphone and 2) On ipad the pop-up is appearing at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing these lines from your index. And see what's happend.

```
.modal { 
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent; 
}

.modal-body { 
  display: inline-block; 
  background-color: #FFF; 
}

.modal img { 
  min-width: none!important; 
}
```

Comment: Previously it was not working so that I added the above code.

Comment: Why you still use bootstrap 2.3?

Comment: I don't have answer for that question since the designer is responsible for it whose decision is to make use of Bootstrap 2.3. Any ways Xm7x's code is working for me on PC and laptop but not on any other devices. Can you help me in this regard please?

Comment: You might need to upgrade to bootstrap 3. I think it has better mobile support.  http://getlevelten.com/blog/felipa-villegas/5-benefits-using-bootstrap

Comment: I agree with @Xm7X. The recent version is more stable and mobile frindlier than the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".modal").css({
'margin-top': function () { //Vertical centering
    return -($(this).height() / 2);
},
'margin-left': function () { //Horizontal centering
    return -($(this).width() / 2);
}
});
```

Comment: Here is another thing you can try

Comment: Your new trick works fine on PC and laptop but it fails on devices like tablet and smart phones. The pop-up doesn't re-size as per the screen size. If you can fix this issue it will be really very helpful for me.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437151/twitter-bootstrap-modal-on-mobile-devices