# Bootstrap Modal disappearing in ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a website where I have used bootstrap modal. When I am testing my website in ipad modal gets opened but whenever i am trying to edit some thing within that pop-up modal, the modal pop-up disappearing but the modal backdrop is still there. 
Can any one tell me why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

different versions of iOS have sometimes undesirable behaviour when focussing on an input - natively it tries to center the input while bringing up the keyboard and seriously messes with the DOM if you have fixed or absolutely positioned elements being affected, if this is your problem then you could try cancelling the auto-focus behaviour - see this answer [Twitter Bootstrap modal on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437151/twitter-bootstrap-modal-on-mobile-devices) for possible solutions.

Comment: @A Macdonald
Thanks a lot. The link you provided was really helpful for me. I think my this issue is solved now. But one more thing I have noticed that whenever my modal pop up is open and I am writing something through my ipad virtual keyboard and then if I click any button in the pop-up without closing the keyboard manually my pop-up also gets closed. Can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: well the bootstrap responsive modal seems to be an issue of pain amongst both the bootsrap devs and users - this modal looks like it fixes all issues http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/,  I would try out the demos, in particular the first one which is a responsive form, on iOS  and if they work then include this in your site and use as directed