# Mobile popup overlay issue

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modalpopup

Im having issue with modal popup in mobile browsers but works fine in web browser.
when i open popup the background blur appears for a sec and hides immediately when touched or scrolled in mobile ,but coming to desktop overlay stays .

```
  qtip-overlay div {

    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem (From Stack Overflow). I don't have privileges to comment, So i will post the answer and mention the source below.

**There is an [unofficial Bootstrap Modal Modification](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal) to address address responsive/mobile issues. This is perhaps the simplest and easiest way to remedy the problem.**

Or you can edit `bootstrap-responsive.css`

```
.modal { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 3%; 
    right: 3%; 
    left: 3%; 
    width: auto; 
    margin: 0; 
}
.modal-body { 
    height: 60%; 
}
```

and `bootstrap.css`

```
.modal-body { 
    max-height: 350px; 
    padding: 15px; 
    overflow-y: auto; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
}
```

Hope this is helpful. The answer was grabbed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437151/twitter-bootstrap-modal-on-mobile-devices), answered by [acconrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535467/acconrad). If you found something useful, Upvote him on the given link.